# How do I ask an off-topic, but important, question on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, opinion-based

I have a rather strange question related to <strike>computer</strike> programming that I need answers to. The question is

> How to explain <strike>computer</strike> programming to a 3-year-old child?

The average Joe, who is a non technical person, is equivalent to a 3 year old when it comes to <strike>computer</strike> programming. **How do I ask this question on Stack Overflow and get answers from fellow programmers?**

Since "opinion" based answers are literally banned on Stack Overflow, which I find ironic as every answer on Stack Overflow is based on someone's opinion as to why his/her answer is right, which is tried and tested, leading to variable answers.

Comment: Your understanding of opinion-based answers is wrong. But, you know, that's just, like, my opinion, man.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to ask this question on Stack Exchange?

Comment: I couldn't think of a better platform filled with proper programmers who are more qualified to answer the said question.

Comment: recommended reading: **[How do I explain ${something} to ${someone}?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6630/31260)**

Comment: So basically I can't get an answer to a question, that can only be truly and properly be be answered by programmers, from a site consisting of programmers from around the globe, and I'm redirected to ask this question on a general site, consisting of the very people to whom I need to answer if they in turn look to me to explain programming to them ? Really ?

Comment: Somehow I imagine you'd get a similar reaction on [Physics.se] when asking how to explain special relativity to a 3-year-old.

Comment: But isn't it considered skill to be able to do that ? I consider that ability to be unique. That is why I asked my question here.

Comment: @Jongware: I did what you said, I asked the question here :  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/155078/how-do-you-explain-special-relativity-to-a-3-year-old-child and I got an upvote instantly !

Comment: And someone answered the answer precisely here : http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31/lay-explanation-of-the-special-theory-of-relativity

Comment: @Jongware: I found what I needed in Physics page, but not here, and the genre of the question was same on both pages

Comment: If it's off-topic, it's off-topic. No amount of importance is going to change that. This is a place where programmers gather, yes, but not everything relevant to programmers is on-topic here. Whether or not another community exists to answer your question doesn't matter; it doesn't belong *here*.

Comment: ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Answer (score 5):

There's several things wrong with this question which make it too subjective for Stack Overflow.

1. "Computer programming" is **very** loosely defined.  Does that mean it's someone that knows how to write their own operating system?  Is it someone that can write websites?  Do they not know how to do anything with networks?  What if they programmed phones and tablets?  Does that not make them a "computer" programmer?

   Given the number of things that could be defined as a "computer", it's difficult to pin down what "computer programming" actually *means*.

   This is why I personally describe myself as a **software engineer**; I actually engineer solutions to problems in a given language or framework.  Programmers (which do exist as a formal title) only write code as given direction by engineers.  I'm loathe to use the phrase "computer programmer" in its complete form again in this answer.
2. Explaining <s>computer</s> programming to someone that is non-technical is just as difficult.  Everyone understands technology differently, and has their own preconceived notions and biases as to what "<s>computer</s> programming" actually means.   For some, it means that they're working on sites like Google and Facebook and Amazon; to others, it means that they're really good with technology and can be relied upon to fix their machines.

   In reality, it can be as simple as writing some code to interact with an Arduino board, whereas for others, it's as complex as architecting and implementing a fully redundant advertisement distribution service, with checks to ensure fair and balanced distribution of ads.
3. The so-called "target audience" implies that they would not need this information.  If you truly believe that they are equivalent to a three-year old when explaining it, then I'm forced to believe that a three-year old doesn't need to understand <s>computer</s> programming in order for them to be functioning members of society.  Someone that wants to seek this knowledge out would first realize the misnomer between <s>computer</s> programmers and software engineers, then seek to understand what it really means to program.

   It's ***difficult*** to distill that to an answer here on Stack Overflow.

Lastly, a counterpoint to this remark:

> ... every answer on Stack Overflow is based on someone's opinion as to why his/her answer is right, which is tried and tested, leading to variable answers.

If you find an example of this sort of answer, please, please **downvote it**.  I would fully expect answers to be backed up with something verifiable.  If they're not, then we need to address that quickly; downvoting is one of the quickest ways to do so.

Comment: Thank you for this piece. I really appreciate it. Though many of your points were valid, IMHO if I even begin to explain programming to a non-tech person, they always have this look of a 3 year old watching a light bulb when it flicks to life. Blank expression. In other words, I need to simplify the explanation of the word PROGRAMMING to the extent where I feel I'm in the presence of a 3 year old child. If my explanation creates an understanding even in a 3 year old, I'm pretty sure I can replicate the results with any adult. I need a very simple yet informative answer.

Comment: Since I'm at loss of words, I needed some well versed, simple, detailing and yet not under powering or overstating the stature of programming. Again, that was a mistake of calling it computer programming. I've edited it .

Comment: I asked the a question on the Physics page of Stack exchange and I got the reply here...... http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/155078/how-do-you-explain-special-relativity-to-a-3-year-old-child?noredirect=1#comment324318_155078

Comment: I found what I needed in Physics page, but not here, and the genre of the question was same on both pages

Comment: @SandySands _"I found what I needed in Physics page"_ It was closed there as _opinion based_ there, without any answer (and that's the correct reaction). Try chat about such stuff ...